# Complex conjugate of the partial derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How would I show that for holomorphic $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, $$\overline {\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} =\frac{\partial \overline f}{\partial x}$$?

My thought is that it must follow somehow from the definition of the partial derivative where $h\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\overline {\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}=\overline{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}}$$

What would I do from here?

Comment: I think it comes down to the fact, that the derivative is linear and the complex conjugation aswell

Comment: Complex conjugation is continuous, so you can bring it inside the limit. Then use algebraic rules of conjugation.  That should get you farther, if not there.

Comment: [nitpick] The $f$ you write down is a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The notation will be simpler if you write $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Perhaps it will also make you see better what to do.